# Is it a normal action from my local wordpress to connect to fonts.googleapis.com?

Tags: wordpress

I have builded a wordpress on my
local 127.0.0.1\wordpress,when start wamp and input `127.0.0.1\wordpress` in the firefox,please see the left corner ,`connecting to fonts.googleapis.com`.
Is that a normal action to link to fonts.googleapis.com  from my local address?Maybe it is not safe for people to use wordpress.

[image]

it is said that to append in the end of functions.php  some codes such as the following  can solved the problem,it run into another error when i append .

```
function remove_open_sans_from_wp_core() {
wp_deregister_style( 'open-sans' );
wp_register_style( 'open-sans', false );
wp_enqueue_style('open-sans','');
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_open_sans_from_wp_core' );
```

How can i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the theme is using it?

Comment: can i change the theme into another one which don't connect to fonts.googleapis.com ?

Comment: Sure, why not? Check for "starter" themes if you want something clean and basic.